# Visual Studio 2013 has stopped working

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am new to WPF and MVVM and am having a problem with Visual Studio 2013.
I create a new class called `RelayCommand` and implement `ICommand` then every time I try to write a event handler for `CanExecuteChanged` Visual Studio crashes with:

> Visual Studio has stopped working

...this is the only time it does this.

Below is the code where the problem arises:

```
 public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    readonly Action<object> _execute;
    readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, null)      
    {

    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
          throw new ArgumentNullException <----- here is where VS crashes
    }
}
```

has anyone had this issue before?

Comment: Is that the exact syntax you're using? Also, it helps to define "crashes".

Comment: by crashes I mean I get a white screen and a message saying Visual Studio has stopped working.

Comment: Could you try adding some more details? Why are you trying to add an event handler to can execute change, assuming that you are going the MVVM way and your ICommand is bound to an event in your xaml?

Comment: Reinstall visual studio.  Obviously, nothing in your application should cause VS to crash.

Comment: after struggling with it all night...I thought it was intellisense because everytime intellisense fired it would crash, so I turned intellesense off and now it doesnt crash....so my question is why would intellesense cause VS to crash ..I have been using VS 2013 for awhile now and never had a problem.